# Ignore click event when Velocity JS animation is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, velocity.js

I'm using Velocity JS but when I click on a button who trigger an animation if I click 10 times on this button the animation will be repated 10 times.

How it's possible to ignore the click event if an animation is running ?

I tried `event.stopPropagation` and `event.preventDefault` but there is no effect.

I tried too `velocity.('stop', true)` but this will stop the animation and restart it at the last position and it looks like a "lag" if I click 10 times on my button.

Then here is my code :

```
$('#btn_animate').on('click', function(e){

    divs.velocity('transition.flipXOut',
        {
            duration :500,
            complete: function() {
                $('#box2').velocity('transition.flipXIn', {duration :800})
            }
        })

});
```

How can I do to avoid the click event when a Velocity JS animation is running ?

Comment: Hew... Hard to reproduce... But what about `$(this).unbind("click")` on top of this `.click()` handler you show... And  `$(this).bind("click")` on `complete`  callback?

Comment: You can use pointer-events: none; for avoid another event.

Comment: The unbind click is nice but the rebind not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to read on a little about Velocity...

You did not provide the "effect registration" part.
I took it in the [Velocity examples](http://velocityjs.org/#uiPack)

```
$.Velocity
    .RegisterEffect("transition.flipXIn", {
        defaultDuration: 700,
        calls: [
            [ { opacity: 1, rotateY: [ 0, -55 ] } ]
        ]
    });
$.Velocity
    .RegisterEffect("transition.flipXOut", {
        defaultDuration: 700,
        calls: [
            [ { opacity: 0, rotateY: 55 } ]
        ],
        reset: { rotateY: 0 }
    });
```

So now, let's define a function that which called "theEffect".
This function does:

- unbind click events from the button
- do the animation
- do the animation callback (which is another animation)
- re-binds `click` events to the button in the second animation callback.

```
var theEffect = function(){
    console.log("UNBINDING click events from the button");
    $('#btn_animate').unbind("click");

    $('#box2').velocity('transition.flipXOut',{
        duration:500,
        complete: function() {
            $('#box2').velocity('transition.flipXIn', {
                duration:800,
                complete: function() {
                    console.log("BINDING click events to the button");
                    $('#btn_animate').bind("click",theEffect);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
// Initial binding
$('#btn_animate').bind("click",theEffect);
```

I got it working in [**this CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jAZgqL?editors=1011).
*(with longest durations)*

Comment: Same. the rebind not working. I tried `$('#btn_animate').bind('click')` too but there is the same problem :/. i'm using JQuery 3.1 is there another way maybe to unbind / bind ?

Comment: Sorry but there is again the problem :(. Maybe there is another solution instead of bind / unbind ?

Comment: I had a missing semi-column... But was that the problem ? If no, show your HTML/CSS so I can try to reproduce.

Comment: Yes I seen. The problem is the same. The unbind works perfectly but when I click again to start the animation again when the animation is completed, I don't have the click event. The bind not working

Comment: Just tell me what is `box2`.. an image ?

Comment: Box2 is a div. But I can make a boolean and check if myboolean is true I can click, when I click on my button then myboolean is false and I set myboolean true at the end of the animation. but I don't know if it's the best way to do that :/

Comment: I think I found your solution. ;)

Comment: Wow nice it works perfectly thanks a lot. But I don't have to register the effect because `transition.flipXOut` and `transition.flipXIn` are in the UI-pack then I can use them without register the effects. That was missing was the callback function inside the `.bind()` -> `$('#btn_animate').bind("click",theEffect);` I just added this and the function and it works perfectly. Thanks you so much !